# How do I make a django model form whose authorization can only be done by admin for positng?

Tags: django

So I have the following models.py

```
class Incubators(models.Model):      # These are our database files for 

the Incubator Portal
    incubator_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    city_location = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=2500)
    rating = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(10)])
    logo = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    picture = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):                  # Displays the following  stuff when a query is made
        return self.incubator_name + '-' + self.owner
```

Now what I am trying to do is create a form for user who has to fill the above field for advertising there incubator on the wall. 
Before posting, I want to make sure that these details get verified by the admin (django admin), and after verification from admin it gets posted on the wall ? Is there any model field for the same specially meant for admin ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
if request.user.is_superuser:

    ...

else:

    raise Http404
```

Comment: I dont think you understood. I want the user to pass the data to admin and the admin would have the choice to post that data or not. How would I use the above condition in this case ?

Comment: I guess it's more of a database design question then? One thing you could do is simply add a boolean to your model that defaults to False, then in all subsequent queries you would have to filter for the boolean to be true. Then you can simply create a form or use the django admin to change the boolean to True. Alternatively you could incorporate the boolean check in your __str__ method. I'm not sure how complicated you want things to be but if you want to work with permissions you will need to use object permissions. A good 3th party package for this I have good exp with is django-guardian.

Comment: You could even use model inheritance in combination with model permissions to achieve what you want. I suppose it depends on your project and your exact needs what route you would want to go.